Screen capture doesn't work (Windows 11)
I upgraded my PC with new parts last month:

Ryzen 7 7800X3D
Asus B650E-F motherboard
2x16 GB G.Skill RAM

I also upgraded to Windows 11 (Pro x64 23H2) when it has become available in Windows Update then.
The computer works fine, but I recently noticed that screen recording doesn't work with Xbox Game Bar, nor with AMD software (my videocard is an MSI Radeon RX580 8GB). Xbox Game Bar is enabled, recording is enabled, and it appears when Windows + G pressed, but Windows + Alt + R doesn't work, and the Start recording button is gray in the small window for recording. In AMD software, simply nothing happens when I press the hotkey for it, or when I click the button in the program.
All drivers have been installed and upgraded, I have no idea, why it doesn't work.
What could be the problem?

Not sure of a fix, but does VLC serve as a workaround to record desktop: https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Record-Your-Screen-With-VLC-Media-Player/ ?
